# Is it possible to make my script faster with running a onEdit() trigger or similar functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I run a script that replaces the input text with the corresponding image.
So for example if the user writes "Austria" it replaces it with an image of the austrian flag.
For that i need to give my function a range and a link.

Thing is the scipt should work in around 600 cells in the same column.
Right now i just run it in a range of 25 cells.

Ideally i just want to run the script in the cell that has been changed.
Right now i just use a for loop to run over the 25 cells which is very inefficient.

Right now i use:

`var calrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Squads!B"+ cellcounter+"");`

This gives me the range "calrange" at the current position of the loop.
So "cellcounter" is my counter of the loop.

I also use

`var calvalue = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Squads!B"+ cellcounter+"").getValue();`

This gives me the value of the cell so i can check with what flag the text needs to be replaced with.

Any ideas on how i can get this scipt to be faster since it woul take ages if i run it on the whole 500 cels?
The function should also only be triggered in that single column.

I have also looked at onEdit() functions but havent worked out on how i can get it to give me the range and value of the cell that has been edited.